# How to fix "File '.\binlog.000327' not found" error?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am using Mysql 8.0 in Laragon on Windows 10.

Apparently, I did something which made MySQL stop working. Tried to restart several times but it's showing this same error again and again.

```
2021-12-15T08:24:35.815298Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010097] [Server] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2021-12-15T08:24:35.815417Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] D:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-8.0.13-winx64\bin\mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 14852
mysqld: File '.\binlog.000327' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
2021-12-15T08:24:42.400102Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010958] [Server] Could not open log file.
2021-12-15T08:24:42.400850Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010041] [Server] Can not init tc log
2021-12-15T08:24:42.401518Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-12-15T08:24:43.574538Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] D:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-8.0.13-winx64\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I do not understand why it's showing. So I looked into the directory.

[image: Mysql Binlog files]

Clearly the binlog.000327 file is missing. Now on google search, I could not find any solution on how to resolve this specific problem.

**Should I copy binlog.000326 and rename it binlog.000327? Will it work?**

I'm skeptical of doing this because it's a binary file and it might cause other issues such as database data loss.

**Or is there a proper fix to this solution?**

Answer (score 0):

NO.  Do not fiddle with the files.

Instead...

What probably happened was that the Primary crashed in the middle of sending stuff to the Replica.

This *may* prevent the problem in the future:

```
sync_binlog = 1
```

To get things going again.  Well, I need to know some more things:

- Are you using Replication?
- Which server (Primary and/or Replica) crashed?
- What was going on just before the problem?

Comment: I'm not using any replication. I don't even know what replication is. I'm using Mysql 8.0 in Laragon for development. Laragon is like Xampp or Wampp tool in which the DB crashed. I changed the port of apache and Nginx and after the restart, the DB crashed. I fixed it by disabling the bin log in some conf file if I'm correct. I don't know what happened and how to properly fix it.

Comment: Strange.  Sorry, but there are too many details missing; I don't know what to ask for.